# How to replace input with text on load if not empty, but also on blur if initially empty and typed into?

Tags: jquery, input

Please help me to improve the following script: http://jsfiddle.net/n9BkM/8/

I need the following fucntionality:

- Value attribute of input field can be blank - then it shows just like now (after entering showing div with change button)
- Input already has some value - there can be some value before the page loads ( http://jsfiddle.net/n9BkM/9/ ) - then it shows the div with change button

How to implement the second step saving the first one functionality?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the switch to div logic into a function and then call it on `blur` like you are doing now, and also on page load.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/KVDBB/

**Note:** I've altered the HTML to have a value inside the input. Make it empty again and you'll see it works as before.

Comment: Could you please make the same but without replacing the elements but just hiding it - it makes impossible to submit the form when the input is replaced ( Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://jsfiddle.net/n9BkM/11/ . Hope this is what you wanted!

Comment: Thanks! Please, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/n9BkM/12/ it shows the input with the value and i need it to be shown as div with change button

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the value:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#consumer-email').val("")
})
```