# Improve the script: hide input if has value and show div with text / get value and show div with text

Tags: jquery

I have a script which do the following things:

http://jsfiddle.net/KVDBB/

-Value attribute of input field can be blank - after entering showing div with change button

-Input already has some value before the page loads - then it shows the div with change button

But the problem is that it uses replaceWith function and replaces the input - while it`s needed to submit the form.

Please help to improve the script for it just to hide input and not replace it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a debugging service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135066/173320)

Comment: this is a duplicate of your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032278/how-to-replace-input-with-text-on-load-if-not-empty-but-also-on-blur-if-initial

Answer (score 1):

Sample here http://jsfiddle.net/deerua/KVDBB/3/

```
$("#consumer-email").blur(function(){
    $(this)
    .attr("readonly","readonly")
    .addClass("noborder");
    $('.changeEmail').show();
}).blur();

$('.changeEmail').bind('click', function(e){
    $("#consumer-email")
        .removeAttr("readonly")
        .removeClass("noborder ");
    $('.changeEmail').hide();
});
```

just use input width **hidden borders** and attribute **disable**
​

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what i need ( Thanks anyway

Comment: explain why, for what reason you need div?

Comment: For styling purposes. I don`t need an input there when the value is entered. It`s not only about the borders..

Comment: you can use div for wrapping input field, and apply style for it

Comment: Sorry but i will use it on textareas also not only with inputs. And i need it to wrap text in a div ;)